# How to hide the light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

The light is not showing at all in the 2nd picture until I add a glass layer. It shows in the render mode and rendered image.

How can I achieve a light effect without rendering it out?

Thanks a lot!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. Select the Point light object.
2. In Object Property, under Visibility, try the settings below. It works for me.

[image]
[image]